# Operador de atribuição "=" javascript

Tags: javascript, operadores

Faço o seguinte:

```js
var d = new Date();
var dataInicial = new Date(2017, 5, 1);
var dataFinal = new Date(2017, 5, 20);

var percorreDatas = function(){
  d = dataInicial;
  while(d <= dataFinal){
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
    console.log("d", d);
    console.log("dataInicial", dataInicial);
  }
}

percorreDatas();
```

Por que a variável "dataInicial" está atualizando junto com a variável "d", se eu não a incremento??????

Comment: Isto é porque objetos em JavaScript se comportam como referencia e não "como valor". Vou tentar detalhar uma resposta

Answer (score 2):

Como o @Guilhere Nascimento comentou, isso ocorre porque os objetos em javaScript são meras referencias para uma posição na memória.

```
var d = new Date();
var dataInicial = new Date(2017, 5, 1);
var dataFinal = new Date(2017, 5, 20);
```

Por exemplo, digamos que a variavel

- `d` é guardada na posição 01 de memória.
- `dataInicial` na posição 02.
- `dataFinal` na posição 03.

Quando você define que `d = dataInicial`, a variavel `d` já não aponta mais para a posicao 01 de memoria, e sim para a posição 02, que é a posição ocupada pela variavel `dataInicial`.

Quando você faz `d.setDate(d.getDate()+1)`, por mais estranho que possa parecer ,você está atualizando a posição 02 de memória, e não a posição 01, que é onde a variavel  `d` foi alocada inicialmente.

Nesse ponto, existem duas variaveis, `d` e `dataInicial`, que, apesar de terem nomes diferentes, sempre terão o mesmo valor, já que ambas apontam para a mesma posição de memória.

Comment: Acho que você pode completar sua resposta indicando como fazer para contornar esse problema.